# How can this function be continuous at all points?

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have an exercise in which I need to determine which functions are continuous for all points

Note: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is floor of $x$.

Function I need to consider is $f(x)= \lfloor x\rfloor+\sqrt{x- \lfloor x\rfloor}$

How can I prove that this function is continuous at integer values if neither  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ nor $\sqrt{x- \lfloor x\rfloor}$ are continuous at integer values?

I can determine it visually from graph and intuitively when considering values close to integers from both sides, but how can I rigorously prove it?

Answer (score 9):

Hint: For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$\lim_{x\to n-} \lfloor x\rfloor=n-1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to n+} \lfloor x\rfloor=n$$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments?rq=1).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, my post is not an incomplete answer, it is a complete hint.  If you don't like this, feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 7):

It's simple to see that it suffices to prove the continuity of $f$ on the integer. So let $n\in\Bbb Z$ then:

$$\lim_{x\to n^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to n^+}n+\sqrt{x-n}=n$$and$$\lim_{x\to n^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to n^-}n-1+\sqrt{x-n+1}=n-1+1=n$$
so
$$\lim_{x\to n^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to n^-}f(x)=n=f(n)$$
hence $f$ is continuous at $n$ and we conclude.

Answer (score 4):

$1-{\bf 1}_{\Bbb Q}$ and ${\bf 1}_{\Bbb Q}$ are *everyhere* discontinuous, but their sum is $1$, which is continuous.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: @vadim123 I think it is quite relevant.